# How to design something like this?

Tags: 3d, drop-shadow, graphic-styles, noise

The shadows and the textured background. I have been trying to work on the adding noise in solid colour but have not been able to get the exact texture like this.
[image]

Comment: That noise looks just like low-quality JPEG compression artifacts to me, no texture applied.

Comment: Have you considered using Blender and pursuing that program to accomplish your goal?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this image is done in 3d using a large area light as a light source (hence the soft shadows)

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe do it in some 3D package (a skill I do not possess) but you can also do it in Photoshop with a bit of bevel/emboss & a drop-shadow…

[image]

I've made no real attempt to match with absolute accuracy, just to hint in the right direction. This took a whole 3 minutes. (If I'd thought about it a little bit longer, I'd have put some of the shadow back into the emboss & perheps 'dented' the flat text surface too, to get that slight vignetting I can see in the original.)
I'd consider the 'texture' in the original to be jpg noise. If I save at lower quality, then my layer starts to look like the original, but the original gets even more distorted.

Settings added to a regular text layer…

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Luciano, fred_dot_u, Sergey Kritskiy and Tetsujin for your comments and answers. I will consider all of them. This is my first attempts at forums. Internet interactions for me have always been on social media sites. 

I wanted to tell you all that I feel so elated that to see you guys (strangers) helping me. Especially Tetsujin who have been so thorough with his answer. Thank you all.

Comment: One more reason that I feel so blessed is after trying for almost 2 months I have finally created a logo for a startup that I am planning that I am satisfied with. For which I have been learning all these design software. 

I am from India. Not from a very rich family but also not from a very poor one. I am 28 years old. I have had lots of dream and expectations with my life. Many have been shattered and few have been not met yet.

Comment: The idea that I have is something I truly believe in. Today I have completed the logo and today joined this forum. After months of stress, self-doubt and ever reducing confidence in myself and the Idea, I feel like I am getting closer to my dream.

I am feeling so so happy.

Seriously guys thanks. I am saying this from my heart. I hope we'll continue this relation based on good will.

Comment: And I hope that you guys fucking drink. 
Because If this startup becomes successful I am going to call all of you to India and we'll drink till we fucking pass out.

Comment: So long as we can "Go out for an English" afterwards - famous Indian/British comedy sketch - https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x6perng (btw, we're not supposed to be chatty in Stack Exchange comment threads, but you get a temporary free pass for being new. These comments will probably get deleted by admin.)

Answer (score 0):

Something resembling is easy to put together in Illustrator. No 3D effects are needed for this:

[image]

On the top there's a texture bitmap image. It's made in Photoshop by inserting noise to solid grey, blurring slightly and applying Filter > Stylize > Emboss to make it look coarse surface. In illustrator it has blending mode Hard Light and low opacity. No guarantee it's the same as in your image because JPG compression artifacts and low resolution blurriness cover much detail. Actually I'm not sure is there any texture image at all, but my version with 100% opacity is this:

[image]

The texture is removed in the next image.

[image]

In the bottom there's a background rectangle (=Path). The rest of the items are different copies of outlined text "Hello". In Illustrator Type > Create Outlines makes groups, which is generally useful because otherwise the parts would easily get moved apart.

The 2 items just above the background are

- a black version with heavy blur and reduced opacity (it's just now selected). That's the long throw shadow moved quite far downwards and leftwards.
- a white version with blur, reduced opacity and blending mode overlay. It's the reflection a little above and to the right.

In the next image the background, the reflection and the long throw shadow are removed:

[image]

The apparent thickness is a Blend between teal and black versions of the text. There are only 10 intermediate versions. The black bottom has reduced opacity to make it look less offensive. The blended texts are not groups. I ungrouped them and made compound paths because blending groups can generate unpredictable results.

Blending with option "Continuous color" inserts in the fly as many intermediate versions as needed to fade the steps, but that makes easily Illustrator slow, so my blend has "10 steps".

On the top there's a teal version of the text with drop shadow effect. In the next image only it is left:

[image]